# How to change column values from date format to free-flowing text is dependent on "result" column in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating R shiny app, when the user inputs values in the columns "schoolid," "userid," "class," "result," and "Date of the result / Remarks for fail" and clicks the button "Add," the related datable is displayed in "Tab2", it works perfectly at present

**What I want is**

If the column "result" is selected to  "pass," the column "Date of the result / Remarks for fail" should be date formatted; otherwise, if the column "result" is selected to "fail," the column "Date of the result / Remarks for fail" should be free-flowing text.

Could someone help with this?

**code**

```
library(shiny)
library(stringr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(tabsetPanel(id='tabs', 
                       tabPanel("Tab1",
                                div(id = "form", 
                                    textInput("schoolId", label="SchoolId *" ),
                                    selectInput("userId", label="UserId", choices = c("UserA", "UserB", "UserC"),selected = "UserA"), 
                                    textInput("class", label = "class"), 
                                    selectInput("result", label="result", choices = c("PASS", "FAIL" )),
                                                dateInput("resultdate", value = NA, label = "Date of the result / Remarks for fail"
                                                          , format = "yyyy-mm-dd" )
                                ),
                                actionButton("add", "Add")
                       ), 
                       tabPanel("Tab2", 
                                tabPanel("View", 
                                         conditionalPanel("input.add != 0", 
                                                          DTOutput("DT2"), hr(), downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'))
                                )
                       )
  )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  store <- reactiveValues()
  
  observeEvent(input$add,{
    new_entry <- data.frame(SCHOOLID=input$schoolId, USERID=input$userId
                            , CLASS= input$class
                            , RESULT=input$result,
                            RESULT_DATE = input$resultdate)
    
    if("value" %in% names(store)){
      store$value<-bind_rows(store$value, new_entry)
    } else {
      store$value<-new_entry
    }
    # If you want to reset the field values after each entry use the following two lines
    for(textInputId in c("schoolId", "class")) updateTextInput(session, textInputId, value = "")
    updateSelectInput(session, "userId", selected = "UserA")
    updateSelectInput(session, "result", selected = "PASS")
    updateDateInput(session, "resultdate")
  })
  output$DT2 <- renderDT({
    store$value
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed the first solution: Here is a complete new solution: With download option:

Main problem was to pass an empty date field to the empty dataframe.

See here [Arguments imply differing number of rows. data.frame() Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71210205/arguments-imply-differing-number-of-rows-data-frame-error/71210338?noredirect=1#comment125874348_71210338)

I have changed `dateInput` with `airDatepickerInput` from  `shinyWidgets`

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  fluidRow(tabsetPanel(id='tabs', 
                       tabPanel("Tab1",
                                div(id = "form", 
                                    textInput("schoolId", 
                                              label="SchoolId *"),
                                    selectInput("userId", 
                                                label="UserId", 
                                                choices = c("UserA", "UserB", "UserC"),
                                                selected = "UserA"), 
                                    textInput("class", 
                                              label = "class"), 
                                    selectInput("result", 
                                                label="result", 
                                                choices = c("PASS", "FAIL" )),
                                    airDatepickerInput("resultdate", 
                                                       label = "Date of the result / Remarks for fail"),
                                    textInput("remarks_fail", 
                                              label =  "Remarks for fail")
                                ),
                                actionButton("add", "Add")
                       ), 
                       tabPanel("Tab2", 
                                tabPanel("View", 
                                         conditionalPanel("input.add != 0", 
                                                          # DTOutput("DT2"), 
                                                          hr(), 
                                                          dataTableOutput('downloadData'))
                                                         # downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'))
                                )
                       )
  )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  store <- reactiveValues()
  
  observeEvent(input$result, {
    if(input$result == "FAIL"){
      shinyjs::disable("resultdate")
      shinyjs::enable("remarks_fail")
      
    } else {
      shinyjs::enable("resultdate")
      shinyjs::disable("remarks_fail")
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add,{
    new_entry <- data.frame(SCHOOLID=input$schoolId, 
                            USERID=input$userId, 
                            CLASS= input$class, 
                            RESULT=input$result,
                            RESULT_DATE =as.Date(ifelse(length(input$resultdate)==0,as.Date(NA),input$resultdate),origin='1970-01-01'),
                            REMARKS_FAIL = input$remarks_fail)
    
    if("value" %in% names(store)){
      store$value<-bind_rows(store$value, new_entry)
    } else {
      store$value<-new_entry
    }
    
    # If you want to reset the field values after each entry use the following two lines
    for(textInputId in c("schoolId", "class", "remarks_fail")) updateTextInput(session, textInputId, value = "")
    updateSelectInput(session, "userId", selected = "")
    updateSelectInput(session, "result", selected = "")
    updateAirDateInput(session, "resultdate", clear = TRUE)
    
    shinyjs::alert("Thank you!")
  })
  
  # Not necessary if used second download option
  # output$DT2 <- renderDT({
  #   store$value
  # })
  
  
  # Option1 download csv
  
  # output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
  #   filename = function(){"thename.csv"}, 
  #   content = function(fname){
  #     write.csv(store$value, fname)
  #   }
  # )
  
  # Option 2 download DataTable
  output$downloadData <- renderDataTable(store$value, extensions = 'Buttons', 
                                options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                               buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'))
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you, However, if I pick "FAIL," as well as adding the remarks, the error appears. `Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0`

Comment: Strange. It has to do with first to select a date. I will check and update.

Comment: Has the Date of results field to have a date always or should it be empty if fail. In case of pass it is clear we have to select a date. But in case of fail which date of result should be applied ?

Comment: If the result is fail the date column should be empty

Comment: I am almost finished. some minutes I need. It turned out to be more complicated!

Comment: Can you also help me download the Datatable (Tap2) to csv?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242216/discussion-between-kevin-tracey-and-tarjae).