# How to download the datatable to .xpt file in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating R shiny app, when the user inputs values in the columns "schoolid," "userid," "class," "result," and "Date of the result / Remarks for fail" and clicks the button "Add," the related datable is displayed in "Tab2", it works perfectly at present.

I am looking for a solution to download the DataTable (from Tab2) to the .xpt file. Can someone help me with this.?

Note: I am asking this new inquiry after referring to my previous one.: [How to change column values from date format to free-flowing text is dependent on "result" column in R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71201796/how-to-change-column-values-from-date-format-to-free-flowing-text-is-dependent-o/71202934?noredirect=1#comment125861942_71202934).

**Code**

```
library(shiny)
library(stringr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(tabsetPanel(id='tabs', 
                       tabPanel("Tab1",
                                div(id = "form", 
                                    textInput("schoolId", label="SchoolId *" ),
                                    selectInput("userId", label="UserId", choices = c("UserA", "UserB", "UserC"),selected = "UserA"), 
                                    textInput("class", label = "class"), 
                                    selectInput("result", label="result", choices = c("PASS", "FAIL" )),
                                                dateInput("resultdate", value = NA, label = "Date of the result / Remarks for fail"
                                                          , format = "yyyy-mm-dd" )
                                ),
                                actionButton("add", "Add")
                       ), 
                       tabPanel("Tab2", 
                                tabPanel("View", 
                                         conditionalPanel("input.add != 0", 
                                                          DTOutput("DT2"), hr(), downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'))
                                )
                       )
  )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  store <- reactiveValues()
  
  observeEvent(input$add,{
    new_entry <- data.frame(SCHOOLID=input$schoolId, USERID=input$userId
                            , CLASS= input$class
                            , RESULT=input$result,
                            RESULT_DATE = input$resultdate)
    
    if("value" %in% names(store)){
      store$value<-bind_rows(store$value, new_entry)
    } else {
      store$value<-new_entry
    }
    # If you want to reset the field values after each entry use the following two lines
    for(textInputId in c("schoolId", "class")) updateTextInput(session, textInputId, value = "")
    updateSelectInput(session, "userId", selected = "UserA")
    updateSelectInput(session, "result", selected = "PASS")
    updateDateInput(session, "resultdate")
  })
  output$DT2 <- renderDT({
    store$value
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try `write_xpt(data, path, version = 8, name = NULL)` from the `haven` package.

Comment: @YBS, However, I'm having trouble determining where my data frame is already stored in a variable. Could you assist me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `write.xport` from `SASxport` package.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(stringr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library("SASxport")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(tabsetPanel(id='tabs', 
                       tabPanel("Tab1",
                                div(id = "form", 
                                    textInput("schoolId", label="SchoolId *" ),
                                    selectInput("userId", label="UserId", choices = c("UserA", "UserB", "UserC"),selected = "UserA"), 
                                    textInput("class", label = "class"), 
                                    selectInput("result", label="result", choices = c("PASS", "FAIL" )),
                                    dateInput("resultdate", value = NA, label = "Date of the result / Remarks for fail"
                                              , format = "yyyy-mm-dd" )
                                ),
                                actionButton("add", "Add")
                       ), 
                       tabPanel("Tab2", 
                                tabPanel("View", 
                                         conditionalPanel("input.add != 0", 
                                                          DTOutput("DT2"), hr(), downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'))
                                )
                       )
  )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  store <- reactiveValues()
  
  observeEvent(input$add,{
    new_entry <- data.frame(SCHOOLID=input$schoolId, USERID=input$userId
                            , CLASS= input$class
                            , RESULT=input$result,
                            RESULT_DATE = input$resultdate)
    
    if("value" %in% names(store)){
      store$value<-bind_rows(store$value, new_entry)
    } else {
      store$value<-new_entry
    }
    # If you want to reset the field values after each entry use the following two lines
    for(textInputId in c("schoolId", "class")) updateTextInput(session, textInputId, value = "")
    updateSelectInput(session, "userId", selected = "UserA")
    updateSelectInput(session, "result", selected = "PASS")
    updateDateInput(session, "resultdate")
  })
  output$DT2 <- renderDT({
    store$value
  })
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = paste0("mydata", ".xpt"),
    content = function(file){
      write.xport(store$value, file = file)
    }
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```